# Get accountexpires from computerobject in AD by using VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to get the date from an attribute called 'accountExpires' of a computer object in Active Directory. If the object haven't been set it just says 'never' and if you look it just have a many numbers. I made this and it working for the attribute 'lastlogon', but not for 'accountExpires'. Maybe someone can help me out.

I'm using VBscript because our company is using this in our loginscript.

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim ADSysInfo, objComputer, lobjDate, laccountExpiresDate, WSHShell
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set ADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objComputer = GetObject("LDAP://" & ADSysInfo.ComputerName)
msgbox objComputer
Set lobjDate = objComputer.get("lastLogon")         '   <----- Working ----->
'   Set lobjDate = objComputer.get("accountExpires")    ' <----- Not Working ----->
msgbox err.number
if IsNull(lobjDate) then
    msgbox "No Date"
else
    laccountExpiresDate = Integer8Date(lobjDate, getLocaltimeZoneBias)
    msgbox laccountExpiresDate
end if

Function Integer8Date(objDate, lngBias)
' Function to convert Integer8 (64-bit) value to a date, adjusted for
' local time zone bias.
  Dim lngAdjust, lngDate, lngHigh, lngLow
  lngAdjust = lngBias
  lngHigh = objDate.HighPart
  lngLow = objdate.LowPart
' Account for bug in IADslargeInteger property methods.
  If lngLow < 0 Then
    lngHigh = lngHigh + 1
  End If
  If (lngHigh = 0) And (lngLow = 0) Then
    lngAdjust = 0
  End If
  lngDate = #1/1/1601# + (((lngHigh * (2 ^ 32)) + lngLow) / 600000000 - lngAdjust) / 1440
  Integer8Date = CDate(lngDate)
End Function  

' Obtain local time zone bias from machine registry.
Function getLocaltimeZoneBias  
  Dim lngBiasKey, lngBias

  lngBiasKey = WSHShell.RegRead("HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias")
  If UCase(TypeName(lngBiasKey)) = "LONG" Then
    lngBias = lngBiasKey
  ElseIf UCase(TypeName(lngBiasKey)) = "VARIANT()" Then
    lngBias = 0
    For k = 0 To UBound(lngBiasKey)
      lngBias = lngBias + (lngBiasKey(k) * 256^k)
    Next
  End If
  getLocaltimeZoneBias = lngBias
End Function 'getLocaltimeZoneBias
```

Comment: Does anyone have some idea why I have these issues?

Comment: Anyone, please?